# how to free memory from a set

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, set

I got a set that includes pointers to an allocated memory, I am using the clear method forexample : `setname.clear();`
and the set itself is getting cleared and his pointers but I still get memory leaks because the allocated memory stays uncleared for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)'s [clear()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/clear/) method does remove elements from the set. However, in your case set contains pointers that are being removed, but the memory they point to is not released. You have to do it manually before the call to `clear()`, for example:

```
struct Deleter
{
  template <typename T>
  void operator () (T *ptr)
  {
     delete ptr;
  }
};

for_each (myset.begin (), myset.end (), Deleter());
```

There is a library in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) called [Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html) that solves this problem.

Comment: Or, if Boost is available, try making it a set of boost::shared_ptr<ElementType> (from Boost.SmartPtr: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).  TR1 has smart_ptr as well, I believe.

Comment: shared_ptr would be a great overhead if pointer is not really shared, but just resides in the set (to avoid copying, for example). This was exactly one of the motivations to to create ptr_container.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko what if the set contains int?

Comment: @Pegah: `int` or `int *`? You don't have to allocate memory on the heap for `int`...

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko I have a set of integer values, I have defined it as a type: typedef __gnu_cxx ::hash_set<int> intset; and then I have a set like this: inset s; now if I write s.clea(); the memory would not be freed, would it?

Answer (score 4):

Set only clears what it allocates itself. If you allocate something yourself, you'll have to clear it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

`Clear()` only removes the pointers not the object it points to. You'll have either to iterate on each object before removing it to `delete` it, or use something like `std::tr1::shared_ptr`  (also in *Boost*).