# How to release the memory a set<int> in class?

Tags: c++, memory, set

Suppose I have a struct:

```
struct Foo {
  std::set<int> nodes;
};
Foo foo;
```

After inserting some elements into `nodes` of `foo`, I want to release the memory that `nodes` holds, and I get some inspirations from [Is std::vector memory freed upon a clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944886/is-stdvector-memory-freed-upon-a-clear)

Can

```
 std::set<int>().swap(foo.nodes)
```

release the memory properly?

My question **differs from** [how to free memory from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779138/how-to-free-memory-from-a-set). Since the `int` is the built-in type, we cannot delete it as a pointer, which is considered in [how to free memory from a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779138/how-to-free-memory-from-a-set).

By the way, `clear()` shall not release the memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to free memory from a set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779138/how-to-free-memory-from-a-set)

Comment: @Dutow `set<int>` is not a set of pointers, we cannot delete it as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779138/how-to-free-memory-from-a-set does.

Comment: `std::vector` is completely different container, why do you assume that `std::ser` has the same behavior?

Comment: @chenzhongpu To me the question is whether you have determined through testing that the memory _needs_ to be released - i.e. whether it isn't released (A) right away or (B) later when required by other allocations. If either of these are true, then there isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`foo.nodes.clear();` will clear the `set`. But note that the C++ runtime may not release the memory immediately back to the operating system, so the effect on memory consumption might be difficult to measure.

`std::set<int>().swap(foo.nodes);` will achieve a similar result, but it does suffer from the overhead of an anonymous temporary being created.

Comment: @chenzhongpu who told you that?

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd also add that the memory is automatically released upon set destruction. I'm not sure if it's obvious for the OP.

Comment: ^ There's definitely a missing `set` there. @chenzhongpu `clear()` _need not **immediately**_ release the memory. But it's available if anything else needs it more later... surely?

Comment: @underscore_d: good point: I've put that in. You'd indeed *hope* that the memory would become available if something else needed it.

Comment: @batsheba: clear() only guarantees that the set does not contain elements anymore, i.e. `size()=0`. Some container actually implementations do retain memory. That's the reason for the `std::set<T>().swap(nodes)` idiom. So if OP really cares about memory being released, I'd advise the latter.

Comment: @peterchen that idiom is for `std::vector` which is known to keep memory indeed. That's why new method `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` added in C++11. Did you think why such method was not added to `std::set`?

Comment: It's much harder for `std::set` *not* to give it's memory back to the runtime library. `std::vector` more than likely would retain the data buffer it's already acquired, as an optimisation strategy.

Comment: Yeah, it's evident why `vector` would benefit from keeping memory around despite deleting its elements, as you might want to re-fill it to the same capacity. But for non-contiguous containers, where - I presume? - it's a lot more likely that every insertion requires a new allocation, one might assume by symmetry that such containers are much more eager to release their previously allocated memory.

Comment: @Slava: fair point. However, as long as std::set::clear does not *guarantee* releasing memory (which I've never seen mentioned, which isn't much), an implementation would be allowed to keep a pool of preallocated nodes around.

Comment: @Slava: it's common practice for vectors to overallocate, *and* explicitely exposed by vector.reserve. that seems to me sufficient reason to provide a `shrink_to_fit()` independent of the question whether `clear()`releases memory.

Comment: @peterchen problem is that `std::set::swap()` does not guarantee releasing memory either.

Comment: @Slava: I was under the impresison that containers will release memory they own (back to the heap) when destroyed. But yeah, you are right, that's just a convenient assumption - by the same raitonale std::set might cache preallocated nodes globally, rather than per instance.

Comment: @peterchen std::set does not even have to cache globally, it does not have to exchange that pool when swapped.